# My emoji codes are red, but there's no problem with the site. How can I fix and should it be fixed

Tags: html

[Emoji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yudaP.png)

So i am doing a school project, where you have to create a website about yourself. I decided to put some emojis to make it cool better and more funny. But the codes are red, even if they are working, is that a problem

attaching the photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is normal behavior it's just a color scheme.

Comment: so it won't harm my website, and there is no need to try to fix it ?